# Program to analyse an unknown binary

Tags: reverse-engineering, archive, binaryfiles

I have a file that is an unknown type, and through the research and data I have gathered on its origins I have determined it may contain multimedia information, much like an archive.

Is there a program that can analyse a binary file and find certain image formats and such, much like an archive repair tool (only one that works for *any* binary file)?

Comment: Not sure this is what you're after, but the unix utility `file` can take a stab at the type of an unknown file.  Aside from that, I'd grab a hex editor, a debugger, the program that generated it, and more of them if possible.

Comment: Try a file id program like http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx

Comment: @Wug been doing that for a few hours now :/ The original binaries are in ELF format which makes them extremely hard to debug.

Comment: @LastCoder Tried Trid already. No luck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout 010 Editor for binary analysis: http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/

I don't like windows tools either, but its powerful and has a trial version.

Cite:

1. Full Find, Replace, Find in Files, and Replace in Files functionality for many different data types.
2. Powerful Binary Comparison tool for analyzing byte-by-byte differences between two files.
3. Use the Histogram tool to count byte occurrences and visualize data.
4. Computes Check Sum/Hash Algorithms including CRC-16, CRC-32, Adler32, MD2, MD4, MD5, RIPEMD160, SHA-1, SHA-256, TIGER, etc.

Here a screen from their page
[image: screenshot]

Comment: HxD is free and can do all of that. :P